# Describe function not working in R

Tags: r, psych

Im trying to use `describe` function from `psych` package. However, I am getting the following error:

> Error in describe(ToothGrowth) : 
>     description must be a string of at least length 1

I made sure to reinstall the package, load it, and attaching an example `data(ToothGrowth)` from the datasets library but still getting this error.

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 

locale: 
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252 
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C 
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252 

attached base packages: 
[1] tools tcltk stats4 splines parallel grid compiler 
[8] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base
```

Comment: Works for me. Could you post the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
 [1] tools     tcltk     stats4    splines   parallel  grid      compiler 
 [8] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

Comment: It doesnt look like `psych` is loaded. Did you do `library("psych")` ?

Comment: @user20650 -> its loaded

Comment: Do you have `testthat` loaded?

Comment: if its loaded should you not have `psych` listed in `other attached packages:`  in your `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @Pascal, yes its loaded

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `testthat::describe` overrides `psych::describe`:

```
library(psych)
data(ToothGrowth)
describe(ToothGrowth)
# Warning in FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
#   no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# Warning in FUN(newX[, i], ...) :
#   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
#       vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad min  max range  skew kurtosis   se
# len      1 60 18.81 7.65  19.25   18.95 9.04 4.2 33.9  29.7 -0.14    -1.04 0.99
# supp*    2 60   NaN   NA     NA     NaN   NA Inf -Inf  -Inf    NA       NA   NA
# dose     3 60  1.17 0.63   1.00    1.15 0.74 0.5  2.0   1.5  0.37    -1.55 0.08

library(testthat)
# Attaching package: ‘testthat’

# The following object is masked from ‘package:psych’:

#     describe    <-- overrides describe function of psych package

# The following object is masked from ‘package:sos’:

#     matches

describe(ToothGrowth)
# Error in describe(ToothGrowth) : 
#   description must be a string of at least length 1
```

One solution is to load `testthat` before `psych`. Another is to say which `describe` function to use:

```
psych::describe(ToothGrowth)
```

Comment: I would recommend @Pascal's second solution, `psych::describe(ToothGrowth)`. This is easier to maintain since the package is specified immediately beside the function.